# Nginx UDP proxy shared connection is busy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, udp, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are proxying UDP packets for a game server through a Nginx reverse proxy. Clients timeout very often because the Nginx can't handle the requests. Initially it works flawlessly, but when more clients are connected to the game server (40-50), we encounter problems.

How could we make Nginx handle it?

Here is the proxy setup

```
stream {
    upstream backend {
        server [server-ip]:[port];
    }

    server {
        listen [port];
        proxy_pass backend;
    }

    server {
        listen [port] udp reuseport;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```

Our error log is full of errors like this:

```
2023/02/18 12:40:29 [alert] 3951459#3951459: *5777636 shared connection is busy while proxying and sending to client, udp client: [client-ip], server: 0.0.0.0:[port], upstream: "[server-ip]:[port]", bytes from/to client:1684904/1724744, bytes from/to upstream:1725538/1684904
```

How can I configure Nginx to handle these UDP packets?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

stream {
upstream backend {
server [server-ip]:[port];
}

```
server {
    listen [port];
    proxy_pass backend;
}

server {
    listen [port] udp reuseport;
    proxy_pass backend;
    proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a old and rare problem. Nginx usually can handle UDP packets just fine (worked fine for literal years for me), but I am currently encountering the same problem.
Some say a small proxy buffer is to blame, or some other Proxy configuration.
One said that its a faulty router.

More Information and configurations to try [newest Answer 2015]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804822/client-closed-prematurely-connection-while-sending-to-client-in-nginx

Blog of the Person that said it was a faulty router [2018]: https://swazzy.com/2018/04/29/evasive-errors